# Does git cherry-pick mean this?

Tags: git

let's say

```
commit A^={toBeRemoved.txt, toBeModified.txt,old.txt} 
commit A={file1.txt(new added),added.txt(new added),toBeModified.txt(modified since A^),old.txt}
commit originally pointed by Branch B={file1.txt,toBeModified.txt,old.txt}
```

then

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick A
```

will produce a new commit A' at the tip of branch B such that

```
A'={file1.txt(diff and merged,conflict possible),toBeModified.txt(diff and merged,conflict possible),added.txt,old.txt(from branch B)}
```

I'm not sure about the meaning of "***Apply the change introduced by the commit***" in the manual. I think the changes introduced by A with regard to A^ here only refer to +***added.txt*** and -***toBeRemoved.txt***. As for the file ***toBeModified.txt***, no matter if it is really modified since A^, it's always possible to cause conflicts just like ***file1.txt*** , which might need to be merged manually.  In other words, **what the final A' looks like depends not only on A and A^, but also on branch B where A' will land**.
I'm asking to make sure if my understanding is right because this part confused me for a long time.

Comment: `cherry-pick` creates a patch with only the contents of the selected commit hashes, and applies it to your currently checked out branch

Comment: So yeah, it only applies the changes between A^ and A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  A cherry pick is technically a merge operation—*merge as a verb*, as I like to put it.

Most Git users soon become familiar with the `git merge` command.  The merge command can run this merging operation, this *merge as a verb* idea.  It can also produce a *merge commit*, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective modifying the noun *commit*.  The phrase *merge commit* is often shortened to *a merge*, which uses the word *merge* as a noun.  It's important not to confuse this *merge as a noun*—the commit that has type *merge*—with the process that produces it: the action of merging, merge as a verb, even though `git merge` does both (in some cases).  The reason it's important to keep these ideas separate is that other Git commands perform the action, the *merge as a verb* part, without ever making a *merge commit*.  The `git cherry-pick` command is one such command.

#### Understanding regular merges

Still, to understand what it means *to do a merge*—the *merge as a verb* operation—it's helpful, I think, to start with what `git merge` does.  The process of doing a merge, as in `git checkout branch1; git merge branch2`, involves first finding a *merge base* commit, so that there are *three* inputs to every merge.

Let's suppose there are two different programmers working on a project.  As is traditional, we'll assume programmer A is named Alice, and programmer B is named Bob.  Alice and Bob start with the same repository and branch, and eventually share their new commits with each other.  The original branch, perhaps `master`, is a straightforward linear series of commits, with newer commits at the right:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Each uppercase letter here stands in for the actual hash ID of the commit.

Alice now clones the repository, so that she has these same commits, and creates her branch `alice`.  On this branch, she makes two new commits:

```
             I--J   <-- alice
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Bob also clones the repository, so that he has the commits through H, and creates his branch `bob`.  On this branch, he makes two commits:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             K--L   <-- bob
```

Remember that *every commit has a unique hash ID*, but *every Git everywhere in the universe* agrees that Alice's commit hash IDs are correct for Alice's two commits, and Bob's commit hash IDs are correct for Bob's.  So we use different stand-in letters `I-J` for Alice's than the `K-L` for Bob's.  When we put these two branches into any Git repository, they retain their commit hash IDs, so we eventually have them combined like this:

```
             I--J   <-- alice
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- bob
```

Whoever controls *this* repository can `git checkout alice; git merge bob`, or `git checkout -b merged alice; git merge bob`.  Just for fun, let's do the latter.   We won't bother to draw in `master` (but the name still exists, still pointing to commit `H`).

```
             I--J   <-- alice, merged (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- bob
```

Since `merged` is the *current* branch (checked-out), that's where the name `HEAD` is attached.  Both names `alice` and `merged` identify commit `J` when we run `git merge bob`.

By selecting commits `J` and `L` to be merged, we tell Git that it should *automatically* locate the best *shared* commit.  That's commit `H`: the one that both Alice and Bob started with.  Technically the merge base is the Lowest Common Ancestor (LCA) of the Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) formed by the commits, and finding the LCA of a DAG uses an algorithm that I've described many times before, but here it's pretty obvious visually that the best shared commit is just commit `H`.

So, having located the proper merge base commit, Git now compares the snapshot associated with commit `H` to the two snapshots associated with commits `J` and `L`.  We can have Git do this in a way that *we*, as humans, can read.  The merge does it in an internal way that is more convenient for programs to read, but the effect is the same.  To *see* this for ourselves, we would use:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J`: this tells us what Alice changed.  That includes line-by-line changes to specific files, but also any newly-created files, entirely-deleted files, and any detected renamed files.  With `git diff`, each of these is printed out so that we can see them.<sup>1</sup>  For `git merge`, Git just saves the changes somewhere convenient for Git.

  Note that we don't look at any of the intermediate commits at all.  We just compare `H` to `J`, to observe the overall effect.
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L`: this tells us what Bob changed.  The process is identical to that with Alice's commits: we don't look at anything in between, just the starting shared merge base `H` and the ending commit `L`, to see what Bob did.

**What `git merge` does next is the heart of the *merge as a verb* process.**  Git *combines* the changes.  Starting from the snapshot in the *merge base*, Git applies all of Alice's changes *and* all of Bob's changes.  When and where they conflict, Git does several things:

- It puts *all three* input files into Git's *index*, which is also called the *staging area*.  These three files go in numbered *staging slots*: slot number 1 is for the copy of the file from the merge base `H`, slot number 2 is for the copy of the file from the current commit `J`, and slot number 3 is for the copy of the file from the other commit `L`.

  In some cases—e.g., if Alice deleted a file where Bob changed the same file—it puts just *two* files into the index.  That also occurs for an "add/add" conflict: there was no file in `H`, and Alice and Bob both created a file with the same name.  (For complex rename cases, there's a bit of a flaw / bug in Git, in which the index copies have multiple names and everything gets overly difficult.  Fortunately this case is pretty rare.)  But in general, conflicts put all three files into the index.
- Then, again for the conflict case, Git does the best it can with merging, and leaves the partially-merged result, plus the un-merged sections of the input files surrounded by conflict markers, in the *work-tree*, in the file you can see and edit.  Remember, the files that are in the index are invisible: you have to copy them *out* of the index before you can use them at all.

  If you are a fan of `git mergetool`, this is what `git mergetool` does: it copies the three input files from the index, into the work-tree where you can see and work on / with them.  Then it runs whatever actual merge-tool you prefer, so that you can see all three of these files, plus of course Git's best-effort at combining them into the work-tree file.  (For myself, I usually prefer to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` and just work with the resulting work-tree copy.)

  Note that you can refer to files in slot 2, from the current or `HEAD` commit, using `--ours`:

  ```
  git checkout --ours path/to/file.ext
  ```

  You can refer to files in slot 3, from the other commit, using `--theirs`.  There is no shorthand for files in slot 1 (though there probably should be: `--base`).

For all the files where there are *no* conflicts, though, Git successfully merges Alice's changes and Bob's changes, or just takes Alice's file (where Bob made no changes), or just takes Bob's file (where Alice made no changes).  Or, often the case for most files, *all three* copies of each file—merge base, Alice's, and Bob's—all match because *nobody changed anything*, in which case *any* copy of the file will do.  These successfully-merged files, with Alice's and Bob's changes combined atop whatever was in the base, are suitable for the new merge commit, and they go into the work-tree and the index/staging-area as automatically-combined by Git.

(Note that it's also possible for Alice and Bob to have made the *same* change, e.g., to fix a typo in a comment.  In this case, Git takes just *one copy* of the otherwise duplicated changes.  This take-one-copy action is not considered a conflict.)

**This completes the merge-as-a-verb portion of the process.**  The `git merge` command then either stops because there was a conflict, or goes on to make the *merge-as-an-adjective* merge commit.  If Git stops with a conflict, it's up to *you* to fix up the mess that Git left behind in both the work-tree and the index, and then finish the process by making the merge commit, by running either `git merge --continue` or `git commit` (both notice that they're finishing up the conflicted merge, and make the final merge commit).  We can draw that here:

```
             I--J   <-- alice
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- merged (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- bob
```

New commit `M` is just like any other commit, in that it has a snapshot (the combined changes from Alice and Bob, applied to the merge base `H`, make up that snapshot) and some metadata: who made the commit (you), when (now), and why (the log message you enter).<sup>2</sup>  What's special about `M` is that it has not just one parent, but *two* parents.  The two parents are, in order, `J` first—because `merged` pointed to `J` before we ran `git merge`—and then `L`, because that was the commit we merged.

---

<sup>1</sup>The output from `git diff` can (and should) be viewed as a *set of instructions* for turning the left-side commit into the right-side commit.  That is, `git diff`'s output may say: *At line 41, delete 2 lines.  Then at what was line 75, insert this one new line.*  For new files, the diff will say *create this new file with these contents* and for deleted files, the diff will say *expect the old file to have these contents; delete that file*.  If you start with a work-tree that has the left-side commit extracted, and follow all these instructions faithfully, you will end up with a work-tree that matches the right-side commit.

Since the diff output has human-readable (and editable) text, you can, of course, apply only *part* of it, or apply all of it plus more.  You can also attempt to apply it to a commit other than the left-side one, and that's what `git format-patch` and `git am` are about.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `git merge` supplies a default message that says that the reason you made the merge was in order to make a merge, and typically also gives the names of one branch (the branch you merged) or both branches (the one you merged, then `into`, then the one you were on).  That second bit of information may occasionally be *slightly* useful, and often there isn't really a lot else to say.  But "Merge branch feature/F" is probably not as good as "Incorporate feature F" followed by an actual description of the feature, for instance.

---

#### Now we can fully understand cherry-pick

When we use `git cherry-pick`, we instruct Git to *copy* some commit.  We start with a commit graph, just as before.  The exact shape of the graph is not that important, as we'll see:

```
...--o--o--...--A'--A--o--o--o   <-- somebranch
            \
             o--o--B   <-- branch
```

Note that I'm calling the *branch* here `branch`, and the *commit* `B`, since I like to use these one-letter stand-ins for commit hashes.  I've called `A`'s parent `A'`, as you did in your question.

When we run `git checkout branch`, that attaches our `HEAD` to the name `branch`, and extracts commit `B` into our index and work-tree.  We can now see and work with the files from commit `B`, at the tip of `branch`, as usual.

When we then run `git cherry-pick A`—giving the hash of `A` directly, or using a name or relative expression that finds commit `A`—Git locates both commit `A` and commit `A'`.  Commit `A'` is simply the parent of `A`.  It must be *the only* parent: if commit `A` is a merge, `git cherry-pick` refuses to pick any of its multiple parents, and gives us an error message saying that *we* must pick that parent ourselves (using the `-m` option).  If we do pick that parent manually—e.g., `git cherry-pick -m 1 A`—then the cherry-pick uses the parent we chose, but usually we cherry-pick non-merges.

Git now runs the usual *merge-as-a-verb* action, but instead of *finding* a merge base, Git just uses the commit `A'` that we chose implicitly.  That's the *merge base* for the two `git diff` operations.  Files from commit `A'` will go into slot 1 of the index, if / when necessary.

What goes into slot 2 of the index is the same as always: the commit we have checked out right now, i.e., commit `B`.  The last slot is for files from commit `A`, the one we said to cherry-pick.  Hence `--ours` refers to files from commit `B` while `--theirs` refers to files from commit `A`.  The mostly-invisible merge base refers to files from commit `A'`, the parent of the `--theirs` commit.

If there are merge conflicts, the cherry-pick operation stops, just like `git merge` stops, leaving the conflicts in the work-tree and the three (or sometimes two) copies of each file in the index.  It's up to you to fix up the mess, then run `git cherry-pick --continue` to make the cherry-pick finish.

If there *aren't* merge conflicts, or after you've fixed things up and run `git cherry-pick --continue`, Git goes on to make a new commit.  As always, the new commit uses whatever is in the index / staging-area.  In all the fully-automatic cases, that's Git's best effort at combining *both* sets of changes, and applying those combined changes to the files from `A'` (the merge base).  The new commit copies the commit *message* from the original commit, too.  You then get a chance to edit that message or not, depending on whether you asked to edit (`--edit`) or not (`--no-edit`).

**In very simple, but also very common, cases**, the diff from `A'` to `B` is small and/or there are no conflicts between that diff and the one from `A'` to `A`.  In such cases, the *result of combining changes* made from `A'` to `A` with those made from `A'` to `B` is the *same* as the result of simply patching commit `B` directly.  And in fact, in some very ancient versions of Git, `git cherry-pick` actually did that—it did not run the whole merge system with commit `A'` as a merge base.  But in complicated situations, the two can produce different results.  So modern Git does a full merge, using `A'` as the merge base, `B` as the current commit, and `A` as the other commit.  That's what you said in your question was your understanding, and that's correct.

#### We can also completely understand `git revert` now

If, instead of `git cherry-pick A`, you run `git revert A` (while on commit `B`), Git once again does a three-way merge.  What changes is that this time, commit `A` is the merge base, commit `B` is the `--ours` commit, and commit `A'`—the parent of `A`—is the other commit.  Conflicts occur when the diff from `A` to `B`, i.e., "what we changed", conflicts with the diff from `A` to `A'`, i.e., "what they changed".  By reversing the diff—producing a set of instructions for modifying commit `A` so as to obtain commit `A'`—the combining of the two diffs has the effect of backing out whatever changes were made from `A'` to `A`.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. All the magic begins to make sense. I think it also explains how git rebase is done, which is just to cherry-pick a sequence of commits. right?

Comment: @ShawnChen: yes, most `git rebase`s (by method anyway) use repeated cherry-pick. However, the non-interactive `git rebase` without additional options defaults to using `git format-patch` and then `git am`, probably for historical reasons. Interactive rebase, or `git rebase -m`, or `git rebase -s <strategy>`, or many other options to rebase, switch to the method that uses repeated cherry-picking.

Comment: Update to above comment: as of Git version 2.26, a plain `git rebase` no longer uses the `am` backend by default: it now means the same as `git rebase -m`.