# Oddness with git merges?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm new to git so this may seem simple to everyone else and I'm just not understanding.

I'm getting ready to start a project with 1 other friend and we've decided to use git as our version control system, so we've been running tests to see how this would work. Here's what we've tested with so far and where we're having issues:

We have 3 branches

- Master
- My Name
- Friends Name

Okay, so:

1. I create a test.txt file directly in master before creating the other 2 branches and leave the txt empty.
2. We create the other 2 branches and I checkout my branch write "Test 1" on line 1 with no other lines, then commit and merge it with master.
3. My friend checkouts his branch and writes "Test 2" on line 1, and "Hotfix" on Line 3, then he commits and merges with master and gets a merge error because the 1 was changed to a 2 on line 1, and because Hotfix was added.

This is a little simplified compared to the tests we are running, but is git really not smart enough the recognize the difference when such a simple change has been made? I can see it asking if 
line 1 should have a 1 or a 2 but why is it complaining about Hotfix being added on a new line?

and I don't think it matters but we've tried the same tests in the Bash CLI for windows, Bash directly in Linux, Github for desktop, Gitkraken, and Gmaster, all to the same results.

Edit, for clarity sake here a a readout of what I did in the terminal: I explained what I did in the commit messages, and while I don't know how to display merge conflicts from the bash terminal, here is a screenshot on the conflict that it prints in vscode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Iaw.jpg.

Also for more, clarity, when the .txt is created, there is 1 line, I put Test (number here) on that precreated line in both branches, and for the friends branch, I created line 2 and 3, and put Hotfix and line 3.

Comment: Thinking over your questions to me in comments on my (now deleted) answer, it seems to me that it might help to know what git does and what a merge is. For a superb essay on what a merge is, in particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053884/341994. And yes, it's an answer by torek too. You should take seriously what torek has to say on these matters; I have _never_ seen them so well explained by anyone else.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the link, I will read it thoroughly,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git believes that changes conflict with each other if they make different changes to the same original source line *or* if the two changes "touch" at the edges.  The reason for the latter is that Git does not know what *order* to put them in.

That is, suppose that, starting from the same empty `test.txt` file, *your* change is:

```
+Test 1
```

(that is, add one line reading `Test 1`) and *his* change is:

```
+Test 2
+Hotfix
```

Git does not know whether to put your line first followed by his two lines, or his two lines first followed by your line.

You said that something he did changed "line 3" though.  There is no line 3.  Perhaps the original supposedly-empty file was actually one *blank* line?  Then *your* change is:

```
-
+Test 1
```

That is, *remove* the empty line and put in the line reading `Test 1`.  *His* change is now:

```
+Test 2

+Hotfix
```

(that is, *keep* the empty line, but add a first and third line).  This change conflicts because you *changed* the blank line and he kept it, or—if we look at this a bit differently—he added a line above and below the blank line, while you changed the blank line.  (Git doesn't look at *changed* lines, but rather only *added and/or deleted* lines, and that is another reason why changes that abut—that touch at edges like this—conflict.)

Either way, you would not have gotten a merge conflict had you changed lines that differed or did not "touch" each other.  That is, suppose the original `text.text` file reads:

```
This test file
has several
lines in it.
```

You make a change that adds `Test 1` at the *top*.  He makes a change that adds `Test 2` and `Hotfix` at the bottom.  When Git compares the version of the file that you both started from—with its three lines—to your version, with four lines, and to his version, with five, Git sees that *your* change is to insert between "line 0" (top of file) and line 1, and his change is to insert after line 3 before "line 4" (bottom of file).  These changes *do not* overlap, so Git can apply both changes to the original three-line file and come up with a six-line file reading:

```
Test 1
This test file
has several
lines in it.
Test 2
Hotfix
```

#### Think about the *merge base*

Another way to put all this is: Git is not adding his changes to *your version* of the file.  Git is not adding your changes to *his version* of the file either.  Git is finding the *merge base* version of the file.

Remember that every commit stores a full, complete snapshot of every file.  So if Git can find *any* commit that you *both* had before you started working, whatever file we're wondering about, Git has some copy of the file in that commit.

The merge base is the "best" commit from which you both started—the one closest to what you both ended up with.  Since you both started from *the same* commit, you both had the *same* version of this file.  Git can therefore run two `git diff` operations.  One finds what *you* changed.  The other finds what *he* changed.  Git's job is to combine the two sets of changes, and apply those combined changes to the *base* copy.

When these changes affect different lines and do not abut, Git can combine them on its own.  When they affect the same lines, or do abut, Git cannot combine them on its own.

Comment: I don't think the OP's example is correct (which I think is also the reason that there's a line 3 in the first place, in a file that should have two lines). In particular I don't think the merging was done quite as described.

Comment: "Git is finding the merge base version of the file" And that is why he got a conflict and I didn't (at first). He branched twice from _the commit with the empty file,_ so when the two branches populated the file differently, merging one into the other caused a conflict.

Comment: @torek To clarify, what your basically saying is that 2 different branches cannot be working on the same script or else you will have merge errors? You answer is obviously a lot more complicated then that, but that means to be that git was not build for people to be working together on the same problem, but rather work on completely different issue's and never touch the same scripts while working.

Comment: It's perfectly OK for two different people to modify the same file in different commits, and then merge those modifications. Git will—or will at least *think* it will—be able to merge these changes on its own *provided* they don't *overlap or abut*. Put some distance, as in some lines of text, between your changes and the other guy's changes, and Git will merge them on its own.