# Understanding git conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I think I might be misunderstanding something about how git handles things, and, therefore, I'm facing some rather annoying conflicts.

I start a new branch A, from master, and start creating new files. Eventually, from branch A, I create branch B, and start working on that as well. A branch A continues to be developed, B needs the changes made in branch A, so I merge A into B, and continue working on both of them.

Times goes on, branch A continues to be developed, until it is merged into master. At this point, I think that, now it has been merged into master, I can do a simply merge master into B, and get all changes from A, and from everyone else as well.

Problem is, now that I'm trying to do that, I'm getting multiple conflicts of "Both added", "Both modified", and such - but on files I haven't changed. I totally understand the conflicts in the files I changed - I caused them, I know it full well.

Thinking my explanation my get confusing, I ventured into Google Slides and created this "amazing" drawing to illustrate my scenario (in which the arrows represent merges, as in "merged master into A", unless they point to the first commit in the branch - in which case they mean "branched off from here"; that is, pretty standard git notation, apart from the arrow direction - not sure here):
[image: er]

---

Regarding files other people changed, I don't understand why are they listed as conflicts. That is, there is a file which has been changed by the time I created branch A, and that same file got changed again when I tried to merge master into B. Sure, branch B still has a super old version of that given file, but, still, shouldn't git recognize that they have not been changed in my commits, and just overwrite them, or whatever it does? What am I missing here?

EDIT: just to clarify, I'm the sole contributor of both branches A and B.

Comment: Did you use merge-with-rebase? Or were some of the files perhaps changed on A/master as well, and those are the conflicts?

Comment: No, just pure git merges, no additional options nor anything.


Not sure about the second part of your question. I mean, those files were changed by other people's commits that got merged into A and B. I supposed that should not be a problem...

Comment: If you add a file in two separate branches (and when I say "a file" I mean a file named the same thing in the same sub-directory of your repository), and then merge, you will get a conflict with "both added", unless the two files are identical, then it's not a problem.

Comment: You are the sole contributor of A and B, but since you have dragged master into it, and try to merge master with your branch, content others have contributed to master will be part of the merge, and may be part of the problem with those conflicts.

Comment: If neither A nor B changed a file, if it was changed on master then that should merge cleanly.

Comment: "If neither A nor B changed a file, if it was changed on master then that should merge cleanly."

So my understanding is correct on this matter. I believed this should be the case, but it is not what is happening. I sure as life didn't change those files (I have no clue what they are about), but, somehow, they are conflicting now.

Apart from that, I get a feeling that this merge feast of mine is not exactly a good practice, but I've never read anything about it. Do you have opinions on that?

Comment: If they are conflicting, they were changed on both branches. It really is as simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your graph drawing is very pretty, but it's rather misleading.

Let's start with a question: which branch are the blue commits on?

This is a trick question.  They're not on *a* branch, they're on *several branches*, plural.  If you say *they're on branch `A`*, well, that's true, but they're *also* on `master` and most of them are *also* on branch `B`.

In your drawing, there are no identifiers for each commit.  This makes them hard to talk about: I could say "the second-from-left grey commit" or "the rightmost blue commit", but that's kind of unwieldy, so let me redraw the graph as text, using single uppercase letters in each commit.  I also won't use arrows here as they're too hard to do in text.

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K--L   <-- master
    \        \            /
     M--N--O--P--Q---R---S   <-- branch-A
         \        \
          T--U--V--W--X--Y--Å--Ø--Z   <-- branch-B
```

That is, the *tip commit* of `master` is commit `L`.  The *tip commit* of `branch-A` is commit `S`.  The *tip commit* of `branch-B` is commit `Z`.

In Git, a branch *name*, like `master`, always points to one single commit.  You get your choice of *which* commit; the commit you select this way is the *tip commit* of the branch.  Any earlier commit that is *reachable from* this tip is also on the branch.  So by starting at `L` and working backwards—leftwards, in these drawings—following the arrows from commit to commit,<sup>1</sup> we go from `L` to `K`, then from `K` to `J`.  But `J` is a *merge commit:* it has two parents, not just one.  So from `J` we go to both `S` *and* `I`.  From those two, we go to both `H` *and* `R`, and on to `G` *and* `Q`, and `F` *and* `P`, and `E`.  There are two ways to reach `E` but we only visit it once anyway.  From here we can go on to `O` and `D`, `N` and `C`, `M` and `B`, and `A`.  So that list of commits is the set of commits that is on `master`.

(Note that we cannot go from `Q` to `W`, though we *can* go the other way, from `W` to `Q`: all the arrows are one way, pointing backwards.)

The set of commits on `branch-A` starts with `S` and goes backwards to `R`, then `Q`, then `P`, then `E` and `O` and `D` and `N` and so on.  All of these commits are also on `master`.

The set of commits on `branch-B` starts at `Z`, moves back through `Ø` and `Å` and `Y` and `X` and `W`, then picks up both `P` and `V`, and then `E` and `O` and `U`, and so on.  There are thus four commits on `branch-B` that are not on any other branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, all of Git's internal arrows point *backwards*.  So you've drawn your arrows backwards by drawing them forwards.  This situation arises because commits are fully read-only: a parent can't know in advance what hash IDs its eventual children might have, but a child commit does know, in advance / at creation time, what parent hash IDs that child has.  So the arrows *must* point backwards.

(In order to move forwards, you tell Git where you want to end up, and then it moves backwards from there, to make sure that it can end up there from some other starting point.)

---

#### How `git merge` works, greatly abbreviated

When you run:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch-B
```

Git must find the *merge base* commit of commits `L` and `Z`.  To do that, it works backwards, as most Git operations do, from these branch tip commits, to find the *best shared commit:* a commit that is reachable from both branch tips, and hence on both branches, but is "closest to the tips" as it were.  In this case, though it's perhaps not immediately obvious, that's commit `Q`.  Start at `L`, go back through `K` to `J` and down to `S` and then `R` and then `Q`.  Meanwhile, start at `Z`, go back to `W` and up to `Q`.  Commits `P`, `E`, `O`, and so on are all also on both branches, but commit `Q` is "better" because it is the last such commit: it is a descendant of all of those commits.

Git will now run two `git diff` commands internally.  This will compare the merge base—commit `Q`—vs the two branch tips:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-Q> <hash-of-L>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-Q> <hash-of-Z>   # what they changed
```

In these two diff listings, if some file appears to be newly-created in *both* branch tips, you will get an add/add conflict for that file.  The file wasn't in `Q`, but it *is* in `L` *and* `Z`.

For files that are in all three commits, Git will attempt to combine any changes shown in the two sets of diffs.  Where these changes do not overlap (and don't "touch at the edges" either), Git can combine them.  Where they do overlap but those overlaps are exactly the same—cover the same original lines in `Q`, and make the *same* changes—Git can combine that by just taking one copy of the change.  All other overlaps result in merge conflicts.

Your job at this point is to resolve any and all conflicts, any way you like.  For instance, in the add/add whole-file conflicts, if the two files match, just pick either one's content.  If not, combine the two files somehow.  When you're done, write the final contents for each conflicted file into the index using `git add`.  This marks the index conflict as "resolved", and you can now run `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to complete the merge.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>`git merge --continue` checks to make sure you're finishing a merge.  If not, it errors out.  If you are, it just runs `git commit`—so there's no real difference either way, unless you aren't actually finishing a conflicted merge.

Comment: Thank you for your time in responding this - it is even funny that your graph is text based, quicker to draw, and more useful than my fancy misleading mess. Living and learning lol.

Thank you for your explanation. Very informative. I ended up, literally, introducing a new line in each file I knew I wanted to keep, stashing them, hard resetting my branch to before one of those previous merges, and making a new merge - only then I popped the stashed changes back. Extremely manual solution, but it worked, and conflicts didn't even show up. I think I'll be more careful when merging. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't git recognize that they have not been changed in my commits, and just overwrite them?

No.

It doesn't matter that *you* didn't change the file. There is nothing in git's head about *who* created the commits or *who* gets priority. Neither `master` nor `b` is "better" in some way.

The point is only that the file as known to `master` and the file as known to `b` differ in a way that cannot be automatically reconciled.

Git can automatically reconcile some differences, obviously; for instance, if a file is different in one branch because line 1 was changed and different in the other branch because line 1000 was changed. But sometimes it just throws up its hands and lets you sort it out. That's not because of *who* changed the file, it's because of the nature of the differences.

As for *what* the differences are, I think it will help to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053884/341994 — that is best essay I have ever read on what a merge is and how it works. It's all about the LCA and the diffs from it to the ends of the branches. In your diagram, the LCA is the second commit from the far left, all the way back at the point where A was first branched off. All the differences between that commit and the end of `master`, and all the differences between that commit and the end of `b`, must be accounted for in order to merge. Well, git is telling you that for this file it can't do that. And if you think about how the file has changed from there to the end of `master` and from there to the end of `b`, you will see why.

It doesn't matter *who* changed the files or *how* you draw the diagram. It doesn't matter that there is a path that describes (in your mind) the history of what happened. All that matters is three states of things: the state of things at the time of that very early commit, the state of things at the end of `master`, and the state of things at the end of `b`.

Comment: That makes sense. What is troubling me is how to handle that. I mean, I merge master in my branch, and, at that time, file "text" has some information. As I keep working on my branch, someone will probably change that file, but that should be fine - as long as my branch doesn't modify it as well, I should be able to merge master into my branch without conflicts, right? That is the point that doesn't quite seem to be summing up for me. Why is it pointing conflicts in files that are only in my branch via merges - that is, the branch does not change them in any way?

Comment: Also, "essay" is quite a good description of what is that answer. It is amazing how people like you and the others spend time actually trying to help people out. Thank you for your time and effort.