# Cherry-picking produces unexpected conflicts

Tags: git

I have a product with following branch versions: `release/4.0`, `release/4.5` and `release/5.0`. Each of these are being maintained separately and each of there have a two main components:

- Site
- Backoffice

All of them share an identical `backoffice` component, but very different `site` component.

During the active development of `backoffice`, I tend to branch out of `release/5.0`, make changes, cherry-pick them to `release/4.0` and `release/4.5`. Up until now, I had no issues with this, however, changes were limited to 5-6 files.

Recently, we have done major overhaul of the `backoffice` - most of the files were changed, some due to code-style (line-breaks/indentations) and some due to implementation requirements.

When I attempt to cherry-pick commits to other branches, I get strange and unexpected conflicts. I feel that my understanding of cherry picking is faulty, but the more I read the more that one seems appropriate.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: If you find yourself doing a heavy amount of cherry-picking it might be time to review your repository structure: you could take all the parts of the code that you know you will be actively developing across all releases and move them into other repos that you fetch into your main repo - the one with the release branches - via git subtree. Adds a bit of complexity but at least you won't be cherry-picking all over the place so it'll be cleaner and safer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does git cherry-pick mean this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051065/does-git-cherry-pick-mean-this)

Comment: Your code/repo architecture sounds very badly designed, but how to fix it depends on your programming language and environment and is a matter of opinion. The way for you personally to understand what’s going on in this particular question is to understand what cherry picking is. Hint: it does not mean “make my code look more like this other commit”.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is rather wrong repo structure. At the time of writing I didn't plan on having different Site sections. In fact, I already planned to chunk it up in separate repos as those need to be separate apps, but somehow always found a way to postpone that. Now, more than ever, it has shown me that need to be done asap... :-/

Answer (score 0):

### Discalmer:

***This is not solution, rather a workaround and a messy one.***

First of all, both @matt and @al-dev are quite correct - this repo's structure is in dire need to refactor.

Since, I needed this right now, I managed to move changes from `release/5.0` to other branches. Cherry-pick was not much of a use as the scope of changes (especially those related to code-style) kept messing my diff context and thus causing lot of conflicts.

As a workaround, I first did `git diff` of `backend` part of app, and then applied it back:

```
git diff --ignore-space-change --binary release/5.0..feature -- src/Backend/ > changes.diff
git apply --allow-binary-replacement --ignore-space-change --reject --whitespace=fix changes
```

Messy and not recommended and I am loosing commit history, but it did a job now. I am going to restructure the repo so I am able to steer clear of cherry-picking habit I picked up for this project.