# git error: `could not revert`, but no details

Tags: git

I am trying to `git revert` a previous commit. I get this error:

```
error: could not revert a135537... commit msg
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

There aren't any conflicts listed. I thought maybe I had to be working in a fresh working directory so I stashed all the new updates but still just get this msg. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `git status` show your conflicts?

Comment: @TTT yes it did, thanks! Although it wasn't entirely clear they were conflicts it seems there was a merge that wasn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

Both `git cherry-pick` and `git revert` are, internally to Git, *merge* operations (see [Does git cherry-pick mean this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56051065/1256452)).  They can therefore produce merge conflicts.  When they do, you must resolve these merge conflicts, then use `git cherry-pick --continue` or `git revert --continue` to resume the operation.

You *should* get an announcement about the actual conflicts before the `error: ...` part.

If you're cherry-picking or reverting a single commit, you can finish the operation (after resolving merge conflicts) with `git commit`, otherwise be sure to use the correct command with `--continue` so that the operation continues with any remaining commits to copy (`cherry-pick`) or back out (`revert`).